# How to show that x-y is Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Which is the cleanest way to show that the difference, $d:R^n\times R^n\rightarrow R^n$, $d(x,y)= x-y$, is Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable? (i.e. foreach A lebesgue measurable in $R^n$, $d^{-1}(A)$ is Lebesgue measurable in $R^n\times R^n$).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Erm, isn't d continuous, and hence automatically measurable?

Comment: Continuity does not imply measurability in Nicolo's strong
sense. There are continuous bijections mapping sets of positive
measure to sets of zero measure (e.g. Cantor sets). Each subset
of a zero-measure Cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero
but its inverse image need not be measurable. Decomposing
the subtraction map as a composite of $(x,y)\mapsto(x-y,x)$
and $(x,y)\mapsto x$ does it cleanly enough for me. The usual
definition of a Lebesgue measurable function requires
the inverse image of a Borel set to be Lebesgue integrable:
this is weaker than Nicolo's condition.

Comment: Another example: the embedding $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$
taking $x$ to $(x,0)$ isn't Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable
in Nicolo's sense.

Comment: Robin is right, every continuous function is Lebesgue-Borel measurable, but it is not said to be Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable. My problem arise from showing that if f is measurable, then is f(x-y). Unlucky if two function $f, g$ are measurable (i.e. Lebesgue-Borel measurable), their composition $f\circ g$ not needs to be. It is if the $g$ is Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable

Comment: @Robin: Please make your comments into an answer.

Comment: Yep, I completely agree!  Sorry!  And I agree that Robin should make this an answer.

Comment: By coincidence (?) we just came to this exact exercise in: G. Folland, *Real Analysis*.  This is Exercise 5 on page 245.  I won't post more until after the class discusses it...

Comment: see Stein and Shakarchi, `Real Analysis' Chapter 2.

Answer (score 19):

Nicolo is asking about functions where the inverse image
of a Lebesgue measurable set is Lebesgue measurable. This
is stronger than the usual definition of measurability
where it is required only the inverse image of each Borel
set must be Lebesgue measurable. Continuous functions need not
be measurable by this stronger criterion. If $B$ has zero
Lebesgue measure and $A=f^{-1}(B)$ has nonzero measure then each
subset of $B$ is Lebesgue measurable but its inverse image may
be non-measurable. A simple example is given by $f:x\mapsto (x,0)$
from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Taking $A$ to be a
non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B=f(A)$ we see this
$f$ is not Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable. More interesting examples
occur on the real line when there are continuous homeomorphisms
from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself taking Cantor sets of positive measure
to Cantor sets of zero measure.

To return to Nicolo's example. Each surjective linear map
from $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable
as it can be decomposed as a composition of linear bijections
and the projection map $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ mapping onto
the first $n$ coordinates (both these types of maps can be seen to
be Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable). By definition, the class
Lebesgue-Lebesgue measurable maps is closed under composition
(unlike the class of Lebesgue-measurable maps!).

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? Of course this answer was very helpful; but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I've thought it was immediate to show that linear bijection are Leb-Leb measurable, but thinking a little more on it there is a thing to show: if $T$ is a linear bijection and $N$ is a Borelian of null measure, is $T(N)$ of null measure?

Comment: @Nicolò: Cover $N$ with balls of very small total measure and think about what $T$ does to each ball...

Comment: Yes, but there are several things to show..

Comment: T is Lipschitz, hence zero-sets go to zero-sets

Answer (score 6):

Unitary matrices preserve measure. A diagonal matrix of full rank is a Lesbesgue-Lesbesgue measurable transformation. Linear maps over the reals have a singular value decomposition.